# Другой шаблон при определенных условиях

Tags: opencart

Для определенных условий хочу сделать что-бы подключался другой шаблон. В header.php добавляю:

```
if(...){
    $this->config->set('config_theme', 'theme_other');
} else {
    $this->config->set('config_theme', 'theme_default');
}
```

но шаблон подключается стандартный. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как подключить другой шаблон?

opencart 2.3

Answer (score 2):

За для общего понимания:

Определение темы, на уровне любого контроллера, просходит на этапе рендера представления этого самого контроллера: `$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('some/route', $data));`

`$this->load->view()` - метод экземпляра класса `Loader()`. Он, в свою очередь, запускает `event-триггеры`, среди которых будет `before-триггер` для данного контроллера. В результате вызывается метод `override` класса `ControllerEventTheme` (`controller/event/theme.php`) И уже в нём проверяется активная тема, сетится в конфиг в `registry` и отдаётся на обработку Твигу, который отдаёт в  `$this->response->setOutput()` готовый `html`.

`header.php`, в котором вы пытаетесь поменять тему, является лишь составной частью того контроллера, который будет вызван по роуту (категория, катра товара, корзина и т.п.) - `$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');`
Подменять тему имеет смысл именно перед рендером страницы, т.е. перед `$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('some/route', $data));` именно в контроллере активного роута (т.е. роута, который был вызван через браузер).

Есть два нюанса. Во-первых, предётся выполнять проверку по условию и сет темы в каждом контроллере, который так или иначе задействован в рендере (или по крайней мере в первом вызваном.). А это как минимум:

```
$data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
$data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
$data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
$data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
$data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
```

Потому что они вызываются раньше, чем основной `setOutput` главного контроллера. Но так же придётся следить за возвращением прежней темы, хз куда пользователь решит перейти по сайту, а это соответствующие проверки считай по всем контроллерам, такое...

Во-вторых, скорее всего всё будет заканчиваться ошибкой **`Error: A theme has not been assigned to this store!`**, потому что тема должна быть активна для данного магазина на ряду с текущей "активной" темой. И я хз, можно так или нет.

Если уже надо замарачиваться с оригинальным дизайном, наверное луше наплодить клонов шаблонов и по условию рендерить через них. Например:

```
рендер категории через разные шаблоны по условию
- копируете category.twig, переименовываете в category_some.twig, стилите, редизайните

controller/product/category.php
...
...
if (some_conditions) {
    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/category', $data));
} else {
   $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('product/category_some', $data));
}
```

**UPD:**
В ответе я указывал **twig**-файлы, которые начали использоваться в opencart с версии **2.3**, в которой ещё параллельно остаётся поддержка **.tpl**. Но это не меняет суть, определение темы происходит одинаково как в **oc2.3**, так и в **oc3**

Comment: Вы не поняли. Нужно не tpl или twig файл другой подключить, а именно тему другую. Т.е. что-бы вместо /catalog/view/theme/default подгружать, например, /catalog/view/theme/other

Comment: этому и посвящены первые 80% ответа